# How to keep a spawner active using command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there a way to make a command block act as a player to keep a spawner active?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `/tickingarea`, it will continue to load the selected chunk as longs as you are online but if you are using a realm or server it will be working with nobody online.

Answer (score 0):

You could place a command block with the following command under the spawner:

```
/summon mobname ~ ~y ~
```

Replace mobname with the mob you want to summon; replace y with the number of blocks the command block is under the spawner + 2. (e.g. If there are 2 blocks between the command block and the spawner use 4)

Then decide how often you want to summon a mob in tenths of a second. Put that number in the Delay In Ticks box of the command block. Then set the command block to repeat, and always active. It should immediately start summoning mobs once per the interval you set. **Make sure you set a delay!!!** Failing to do so will cause a mob to spawn ten times per second, quickly lagging the world. If you accidently do this, break the command block.

You may also want to break the spawner and replace it with one that doesn't have a mob egg in it, otherwise it will create mobs in addition to the mobs being summoned by the command block.

---

This is not exactly what you asked for, but this is the closest I can think of. Hope this is still helpful!